# Laravel best way to save data one to one relationships?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

Terms table:

- term_id
- name
- slug

Term_taxonomy table:

- term_taxonomy_id
- term_id
- description

My Term model:

```
public function TermTaxonomy(){
    return $this->hasOne('TermTaxonomy');
}

public function saveCategory($data){
    $validator = Validator::make($data,$this->rules);
    if($validator->passes()){
        $this->name = $data['name'];
        $this->slug = $data['slug'];
        if($this->save()){
            $category_taxo = new TermTaxonomy;
            $category_taxo->term_id = $this->lastCategoryId();
            $category_taxo->taxonomy = 'category';
            $category_taxo->description = $data['description'];
            if($category_taxo->save()){
                return true;
            }else{
                return false;
            }
        }else{
                return false;
        }
    }else{
        $this->errors = $validator;
        return false;
    } 
}
```

My TermTaxonomy model:

```
public function Term(){
    return $this->belongsTo('Term');
}
```

then in my CategoriesController

```
public function store()
{
    $data = Input::all();
    $category = new Term;
    if($category->saveCategory($data)){
        return Redirect::route('admin_posts_categories')->withSuccess('Category successfully added.');
    }
    else{
        return Redirect::route('admin_posts_categories')->withError('Failed to add category.')->withErrors($category->validation_messages())->withInput();
    }
}
```

It works, but i think my laravel code very ugly, is there any best way method to save data one to one relationships and how to use it ?

Thanks, sorry i am new in laravel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is good.. but you can save your relationship directly without

```
$category_taxo->term_id = $this->lastCategoryId();
```

Try this:

```
public function saveCategory($data){
    $validator = Validator::make($data,$this->rules);
    if($validator->passes()){
        $this->name = $data['name'];
        $this->slug = $data['slug'];
        if($this->save()){
            # new TermTaxonomy
            $TermTaxonomy = new TermTaxonomy;
            $TermTaxonomy->taxonomy = 'category';
            $TermTaxonomy->description = $data['description'];
            # Save related TermTaxonomy
            if($this->TermTaxonomy()->save($TermTaxonomy)){
                return true;
            }else{
                return false;
            }
        }else{
                return false;
        }
    }else{
        $this->errors = $validator;
        return false;
    } 
}
```

Comment: what about if use push() ? @goldlife