# Laravel How to update one to one relationships?

Tags: php, class, laravel, laravel-4

Terms table:

- term_id
- name
- slug

Term_taxonomy table:

- term_taxonomy_id
- term_id
- description

My Term model:

```
public function TermTaxonomy(){
    return $this->hasOne('TermTaxonomy');
}
```

My TermTaxonomy model:

```
public function Term(){
    return $this->belongsTo('Term');
}
```

My Categories controller:

```
public function update($id){
    echo "$id"; // echo success
    echo $data['name']; // it should update name field in term table
    echo $data['slug']; // it should update slug field in term table
    echo $data['TermTaxonomy']['description']; // it should update description field in termtaxonomy table
}
```

how i can update one to one relationships ? maybe with push()

Thanks, sorry i am new in laravel.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Laravel best way to save data one to one relationships?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28107658/laravel-best-way-to-save-data-one-to-one-relationships)

Comment: i think, this not duplicate since this question is how to update. then i want to know how to update. thanks.

Answer (score 15):

You can use Eloquent's `update()` method: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent#updates

```
$Term = Term::with('TermTaxonomy')->find($id);
$Term->name = $data['name'];
$Term->slug = $data['slug'];

// Save The Term first
$Term->save();

// Now update the relation
$Term->TermTaxonomy->update([
    'taxonomy' => 'category',
    'description' => $data['TermTaxonomy']['description']
]);
```

Answer (score 2):

as Jarek Tkaczyk comment in [this question Laravel eloquent: Update A Model And its Relationships](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24200089/laravel-eloquent-update-a-model-and-its-relationships)

> There is no other way, as Eloquent currently doesn't know what
>   relations are on the model until you call them as dynamic property,
>   load with load method, eager load etc. (push works only with loaded
>   relations that are present in model's relations array)

so i use this code.

```
$Term = Term::with('TermTaxonomy')->find($id);
$Term->name = $data['name'];
$Term->slug = $data['slug'];
$Term->TermTaxonomy->taxonomy = 'category';
$Term->TermTaxonomy->description = $data['TermTaxonomy']['description'];
$Term->push();
```

and it works. Term and TermTaxonomy table is updated, but if change push() to save() it only update Term table even TermTaxonomy relationships already loaded with Eager load `Term::with('TermTaxonomy')`

Thanks for all :D

Comment: One thing to keep in mind is that, `push` will update all the `updated_at` timestamps of any loaded relations, even if they were not changed. When using the `updated` method, to save any changed relation data, you will have better control on which data is being updated, and will keep that `updated_at` timestamp more accurate, since it will update it on that changed relation only. 
Depending on the project, this could be quite useful and valuable.